# C# - mciSendString, any solution to get the buffer (array)?

Tags: c#, buffer, wav, dllimport, mci

I'm creating a reader / recorder using MCI through the DllImport of winmm.dll: mciSendString [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797783%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
It works for many things, recording, playing, that's pretty cool. I would like to do some processing on it now but I did not find any proper way, method, trick to get the buffer during the recording (array)? (without saving to a WAV file first).

Any idea?

"Provide a code sample that shows which buffer you want to get. – JeffRSon yesterday"
=> I want to perform a fft on this buffer (would say a Single[] precision array), I already implemented a fft to do this. The fact is that I have no idea to get any direct information except that by save the record into a file and then process it. 
=> I would like to perform a "real-time" audio processing, or a least figure out how to set an event to get every 4000 bytes the buffer containing the data (I guess there is one, but the MCI document is not quite clear enough for me)...

Edit II: I found a partial solution here (still with MCI): [see here](http://winmm.codeplex.com/)
and here: [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573/)

I will try to put an answer as soon as possible, I do not agree with the idea, that, as long as you get some sources related to the topic the answer is provided in. I prefer to put my own code and showing that it works.

Comment: Provide a code sample that shows which buffer you want to get.

Comment: I edited the original post, see above, it's hard for me to write a sample of code expect cause I dunno what the possibilities for the MCI library to get the buffer of data.

Comment: As I understand your description, your app already records audio. Why not post such a snippet and tell what you want to change? However, I would suppose that MCI is not the right way to do this. You may want to look into DirectSound or un4seen's Bass.Net.